# Saving Outlook Attachments Automatically Based On Attachment File Name Only

Tags: vba, email, outlook, email-attachments

I need to save an Outlook file attachment with a static file name to a specific network location automatically when that email arrives.  This file will be saved in a network location for upload using a monthly SSI server package.   I hope to do this automatically without any interaction but not opposed to manually running a macro.  I am unsure of references that are needed in VBA to get this to execute.  I am also unfamiliar with the "ThisOutlookSession" configuration that I've seen in similar threads

I have attempted to use the existing script that I've seen here with no luck. ( I can get them to run without error but do not get any results )  I want to search all incoming email and only have it take action if the email has an attachment and that attachment has a specific unchanging file name. I have the developer tab enabled in Outlook and can access VBA through it. Looking for a solid simple solution. Constants are the file name and extension as well as the network folder. Variables would be the sender and date of delivery. Office 365 running Windows 10 in a professional environment. Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle incoming emails in Outlook in the `NewMailEx` event handler. The event fires once for every received item that is processed by Microsoft Outlook. The item can be one of several different item types, for example, `MailItem`, `MeetingItem`, or `SharingItem`. The `EntryIDsCollection` string contains the Entry ID that corresponds to that item. Use the Entry ID string to call the [NameSpace.GetItemFromID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getitemfromid) method and process the item. The `NewMailEx` event fires when a new message arrives in the Inbox and before client rule processing occurs.

Also, as a possible workaround, you may consider handling the `ItemAdd` event on the Inbox folder. This event is fired when one or more items are added to the specified collection. This event does not run when a large number of items are added to the folder at once. For example:

```
Public WithEvents myOlItems As Outlook.Items 

Public Sub Application_Startup()
 Set myOlItems = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts).Items 
End Sub 
 
Private Sub myOlItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object) 
 MsgBox Item.Attachments.Count
End Sub
```